# Print longest Palindromic substring

Tags: string, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I have written the below code to find the length of longest palindromic substring which returns correct result.
I want to recover the value of longest substring .How can i do it?

```
String s ="babaddab";
int len=s.length() ;
helper(s,0,len-1); //call
 s ="babaddab"; //longest substring is of length 6 ,method should return "baddab"
 s ="cbbd"; //longest substring is of length 2,,method should return "bb"
 public static int helper(String s ,int i ,int j)
     {
         if(i==j)
         return 1;
         if(i >j)
         return 0;
         if( s.charAt(i)==s.charAt(j) )
         {
             return 2 + helper(s,i+1,j-1);
         } else 
         {
             return   Math.max(helper(s,i+1,j),helper(s,i,j-1));
         }
     }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursion: Longest Palindrome Substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66166793/recursion-longest-palindrome-substring). Instead of returning the length, return indices and use those indices to compute the lengths per frame.

Comment: What does this code return when s = "abca"? The correct answer is 1.

Comment: correct .my code gives correct value for longest palindromic subsequence not substring.will fix it

Comment: An easy solution https://youtu.be/Q3CdnFul4iE